# Tkinter tabular display

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I have exactly this type of data in console

```
['0.0.0.0' 68 '255.5.55.5' 67 '04/05/2021 02:42:15 AM'] Threat
['4.37.53.24' 67 '5.225.5.255' 68 '04/05/2021 02:42:15 AM'] Threat
['503.637.53.15' 385 '8.8.9.8' 53 '04/05/2021 02:42:17 AM'] Ok
['23.27.43.65' 446 '8.8.8.8' 53 '04/05/2021 02:42:17 AM'] Ok
['23.27.53.5' 814 '172.217.24.78' 443 '04/05/2021 02:42:17 AM'] Ok
['8.1.0.1' 0 '8.1.6.1' 0 '04/05/2021 02:42:17 AM'] Ok
```

It is generated with below code. The problem is that I want to display in proper columns and rows shape, I am using tkinter library for Gui purpose. In Tkinter I have tried tksheet but It doesn't work in this case. How can I display this in proper column and row form? Which Gui tkinter widget supports that?

```
from tkinter import ttk
columns = ('#1', '#2', '#3', '#4', '#5', '#6')

tree = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=columns, show='headings')

# define headings
tree.heading('#1', text='S-IP')
tree.heading('#2', text='S-Port')
tree.heading('#3', text='D-IP')
tree.heading('#4', text='D-port')
tree.heading('#5', text='Time-Stamp')
tree.heading('#6', text='Status')
tree.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')


df = pd.read_csv('Flo.csv')
classifier_model_reloaded = pickle.load(open('pickle_model.pkl', 'rb'))
predictions=classifier_model_reloaded.predict(X)
for i in range(len(predictions)):
     num = '%d' % (predictions[i])
     if int(num) == 0:
        results.append('OK')
     else:
        results.append('Threat')
     for i in range(len(results)):          
            k = (df.loc[i, ["Src IP", "Src Port", "Dst IP", "Dst Port", "Timestamp" ]].values, results[i])
            tree.insert('', tk.END, values=k)
```

Comment: Have you tried using `ttk.Treeview`?

Comment: No, I have not tried. Will this data move smoothly on that? @TheLizzard

Comment: @TheLizzard I have used it and added its display:( how can I correctly display values in columns

Comment: I am not a `Treeview` expert but have a look at [this](https://riptutorial.com/tkinter/example/31880/treeview--basic-example)

Comment: It is because `k` is something like `[[...], "OK"]`.  You need to append `OK` into the list (`k[0]`) and pass this list to `values` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `k` in the following line:

```
k = (df.loc[i, ["Src IP", "Src Port", "Dst IP", "Dst Port", "Timestamp" ]].values, results[i])
```

is a tuple with 2 items: `numpy.ndarray` instance and a string.

You need to merge the `numpy.ndarray` instance and the string into a tuple or list:

```
k = df.loc[i, ["Src IP", "Src Port", "Dst IP", "Dst Port", "Timestamp"]].values.tolist() + [results[i]]
```

Comment: yeah but how can I add names of specific columns like k = list(df.loc[i, list(df.columns ["Src IP", "Src Port", "Dst IP", "Dst Port", "Timestamp" ])].values) + [results[i]] is not working

Comment: as I have many columns so, I need to specify in command @acw1668

Comment: Use `k = df.loc[i, ["Src IP", "Src Port", "Dst IP", "Dst Port", "Timestamp"]].tolist() + [result[i]]`.